# Visual Studio 2013 web forms project (.NET 4.5 and above) fails when deployed to hosting service. Runs locally

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've recently been working with ASP.NET again and decided to create a small ASP.NET project in a subfolder on one of my websites. I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and created the project using the ASP.NET Web Forms Application template. After creating the project, I left everything at the default, verified that it would build locally, published it to a folder on my system and then copied the published files via FTP to the subfolder on my site. When I tried to bring it up in my browser, it failed with the code **ERR_CONNECTION_RESET**. This told me that the host was seeing *something* there, otherwise it would have gone to my site's main 404 page. Chrome also refused to load the other pages within the deployed template. I did set the folder as an application in IIS after getting another error about forms authentication but that didn't have any effect.

I was able to successfully re-deploy an old ASP.NET site created with .NET 4.0 in VS2010. I was also able to deploy and load a project created in VS2013 / ASP.NET 4.5.1 with the ASP.NET *Empty* Web Application template.

I finally finally get the Web Forms template to work by doing the following -

1. Created a basic Default.aspx page with no master page.
2. Created a basic web.config file (copied from another new empty
   project)
3. Commented out the following lines in the Application_Start function of Global.asax

   ```
       BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
       AuthConfig.RegisterOpenAuth();
       RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
   ```

At that point, the project ran on the host with no problem. I then restored the Default.aspx and Web.config files and the project again failed, even with the Global.asax lines still commented.

I also changed the SessionState mode to "Custom" as suggested in the web.config file and this made no difference.

My question at this point is this - **Has anyone else deployed a .NET 4.5.1 Web Forms app designed from the VS2013 template to a shared hosting service and is there something that you have to do to get it to work?**

I'm fairly satisfied at this point that I can use the empty web application template and build things from scratch but I'd like to know if anyone else has run into this and what they did.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

ERR_CONNECTION_RESET sounds to me like you were having some kind of Internet connectivity troubles, or your server was having some sort of Internet connectivity trouble. If it's working fine now, probably nothing to worry about.

**Has anyone else deployed a .NET 4.5.1 Web Forms app designed from the VS2013 template to a shared hosting service and is there something that you have to do to get it to work?** Yes, lots of people have done that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My connection is stable and I was able to access other sites as well as my main site even when the error was appearing on the test project so the server connection was not at fault. This seems to indicate that there is an issue somewhere in the project files. The error consistently appears when trying to load a project generated with the web forms template. The problem isn't really fixed, I just found a workaround by using an empty template and working from scratch.